# Splunk REST API - How to add a webhook action?

Tags: rest, curl, webhooks, splunk, splunk-api

I want to create an alert, and add a webhook action to it. However, looking at the [Splunk documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/RESTREF/RESTsearch#saved.2Fsearches), it doesn't seem to say how to do it.

Here is my current request:

```
curl -s -k -u admin:password https://splunk.rf:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/saved/searches > /dev/null \
  -d name=bruteforcetest \
  --data-urlencode output_mode='json' \
  --data-urlencode alert.digest_mode='0' \
  --data-urlencode alert.expires='24h' \
  --data-urlencode alert.managedBy='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.severity='3' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.fields='source_ip' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.period='2m' \
  --data-urlencode alert_comparator='greater than' \
  --data-urlencode alert_condition='' \
  --data-urlencode alert_threshold='20' \
  --data-urlencode alert_type='number of events' \
  --data-urlencode alert.track='1' \
  --data-urlencode cron_schedule='* * * * *' \
  --data-urlencode description='' \
  --data-urlencode disabled='0' \
  --data-urlencode displayview='' \
  --data-urlencode is_scheduled='1' \
  --data-urlencode is_visible='1' \
  --data-urlencode max_concurrent='1' \
  --data-urlencode realtime_schedule='1' \
  --data-urlencode restart_on_searchpeer_add='1' \
  --data-urlencode run_n_times='0' \
  --data-urlencode run_on_startup='0' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_priority='default' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_window='0' \
  --data-urlencode dispatch.earliest_time='rt-2m' \
  --data-urlencode dispatch.latest_time='rt-0m' \
  --data-urlencode display.events.fields='["host","source","sourcetype", "source_ip"]' \
  --data-urlencode search='"error: invalid login credentials for user"'
```

How can I modify this request to add a webhook action? The webhook query should be to `http://firewall.mycompany/ban`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parameters you need to specify to create a webhook action:

```
actions='webhook'
action.webhook.param.url='http://firewall.mycompany/ban'
```

Here is your request, modified to include a webhook action:

```
curl -s -k -u admin:password https://splunk.rf:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/saved/searches > /dev/null \
  -d name=bruteforcetest \
  --data-urlencode actions='webhook' \
  --data-urlencode action.webhook.param.url='http://firewall.mycompany/ban' \
  --data-urlencode output_mode='json' \
  --data-urlencode alert.digest_mode='0' \
  --data-urlencode alert.expires='24h' \
  --data-urlencode alert.managedBy='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.severity='3' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.fields='source_ip' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.period='2m' \
  --data-urlencode alert_comparator='greater than' \
  --data-urlencode alert_condition='' \
  --data-urlencode alert_threshold='20' \
  --data-urlencode alert_type='number of events' \
  --data-urlencode alert.track='1' \
  --data-urlencode cron_schedule='* * * * *' \
  --data-urlencode description='' \
  --data-urlencode disabled='0' \
  --data-urlencode displayview='' \
  --data-urlencode is_scheduled='1' \
  --data-urlencode is_visible='1' \
  --data-urlencode max_concurrent='1' \
  --data-urlencode realtime_schedule='1' \
  --data-urlencode restart_on_searchpeer_add='1' \
  --data-urlencode run_n_times='0' \
  --data-urlencode run_on_startup='0' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_priority='default' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_window='0' \
  --data-urlencode dispatch.earliest_time='rt-2m' \
  --data-urlencode dispatch.latest_time='rt-0m' \
  --data-urlencode display.events.fields='["host","source","sourcetype", "source_ip"]' \
  --data-urlencode search='"error: invalid login credentials for user"'
```